# How to set Eclipse CDT to use GCC-4 instead of GCC?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

How to set Eclipse CDT to use GCC-4 instead of GCC?

I'm asking this question, because i'm using windows 64 bits with Cygwin and gcc.exe does not work. I need to configure Eclipse CDT to use gcc-4.exe. But I don't know how to set it up. I cannot find where to change this setting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using Eclipse on OSX, not Windows, so I cannot explain exactly how to do it for cygwin, but to change the compiler you go to the project properties->c/c++ Build->settings->gcc c++ compiler and change the "command" option from g++ to where-ever gcc-4.exe is.  You may also need to change the PATH environment variable in c/c++ Build->Environment, and also the compiler used in c/c++ build->Discovery Options.